# Не могу запустить haskell файл через runhaskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

я установил на компьютер stack и выполнил команду по этой ссылке https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/ (ОС - Windows 10)

Содержимое main.hs

```
main = print 2
```

находясь в папке в которой лежит main.hs пишу в консоль

```
runhaskell main.hs
```

но вместо того чтобы выводить '2'. выводит ошибку:

```
main.hs:0:53: error:

* Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0

* Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)
```

[image]

я только начинаю изучать haskell и никак не могу разобраться как мне запускать файлы, я перепробовал runhaskell, ghc, ghci, но везде одна и та же ошибка

Comment: `main.hs:0:53` намекает, что в main.hs совсем не то, что приведено в вопросе

Comment: Может вы просто забили сохранить файл в редакторе?

Comment: спасибо, да, дело действительно было в том что я не сохранил файл в vs code, я до этого кодил только в webstorm :)

Answer (score 0):

Просто не сохранил файл в VS Code. Оказывается этот редактор по умолчанию не меняет файл до тех пор пока не нажмёшь `Ctrl + S`.

Comment: Любой редактор имеет такое поведение, разве нет?